# WordPress website with high Ram usage (on a VPS server) is crashing

Tags: database, wordpress, ram, vps

I operate this WordPress website - menstrualcupreviews(dot)net, it is on a VPS server with 2GB RAM and 2 core-CPU. I noticed I got many connections from the server to itself and also from the active users.

My guess was something with the sidebar of the website - it is manually included from each page\post with full path (include "http://...."), and the file also includes few other files in the same way (full path with http).

In some point when we got only 20-30 online visitors, It had 1800+ self connections (on a 2GB RAM) from the server IP to itself and it caused the server to crash.

I have changed it to be relative path (without the "http://"), and the number of self connections dropped from 1800+ to about 50-60 self connections, and also upgraded the RAM to be 8GB.

Now, we currently get around 100-200 online visitors and I get
Mem:   8059424k total,  6759236k used, which is not far from crashing again.
The 8GB RAM memory and CPU are on such a high load and I am sure the website need to be optimized.

**For example in a given moment with about 150 visitors:**

ss -tuna | awk '{print $6}' | cut -d : -f1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head

- 108 198.1.72.1 (==>The SERVER IP - 108 self connections!!!)
- 51 186.237.5.188
- 31 *
- 20 177.216.202.135
- 15 168.90.64.203
- 14 201.37.162.119
- 14 177.182.1.136
- 13
- 12 191.251.41.105
- 12 186.212.162.110

I am not sure what causing those self connections OR many connections from random IP's I guess are some visitors.

Any ideas how to solve the high load and if those connections are the reason?

Thanks in advance! (-: